# Using @Scheduled in spring results in java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Tags: eclipse, spring-scheduled, gretty

I have a Spring class which is executing a scheduled task every minute.

```
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)
    public void run() throws InterruptedException {
        processData();
    }
```

I then run this in eclipse using gretty. It works fine but when I do an appStop and then an appStart. I get the following error

> SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8993"]
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

I have searched for a solution and most suggest identifying and killing the relevant process. I was hoping for a better understanding of what the issue is and a more nuanced solution please

Comment: how do you stop your app? it is probably not quite correct as some process is hanging. Or do you you have a second instance of your app still running?

Comment: thanks, no I dont have a second instance I use appStop gradle task

Comment: Depending on your OS, check if that port is still open after stop. If Linux `netstat -nlt | grep <your port>`.